# Using Hunch on Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hunch

I want to use Hunch on Google App Engine in Python. What libraries do I need to use to do this or are there any good online tutorials that could help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start from the [API Overview documentation](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/docs/) of the [official site](http://hunch.com/).

Basically Hunch API calls are [authenticated](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/docs/auth/) GET or POST HTTP requests where the returned values are [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) encoded.

**Example:**
get the list of the top recommended movies:
[http://api.hunch.com/api/v1/**get-recommendations**/?topic_ids=all_544&limit=10](http://api.hunch.com/api/v1/get-recommendations/?topic_ids=all_544&limit=10)

[get-recommendation](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/docs/reference/#get-recommendations) is just one of the many available routes that Hunch API offers; to get an overview of all the available methods, have fun playing with the [API console](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/resources/console/).

On google App Engine you would need:

- [UrlFetch API](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html)  to make the HTTP Api calls
- [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) to decode the results

Here are a couple of Hunch GAE projects that should help you to get started:

- [hunch-gift-app](https://github.com/hunch/hunch-gift-app)
- [hunch-sample-app](https://github.com/hunch/hunch-sample-app)

As referenced by gleitz, you can find a Python wrapper [here](https://github.com/mnn2104/HunchPy).

Answer (score 2):

Recently, [mnn2104](https://github.com/mnn2104) wrote a Python wrapper for the Hunch API called [HunchPY](https://github.com/mnn2104/HunchPy).

As for tutorials, a good place to start is the [the Hunch Developer homepage](http://hunch.com/developers/) and [Hunch's Github profile](https://github.com/hunch).